# I want to be notified by email of error messages when executing Snowflake tasks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to ask how to notify the error message when executing a task by e-mail.

As a premise, I know that notification is possible using AWS (S3 and Lambda, SNS).
But is there a way to notify emails with Snowflake's default features?

Thank you for your confirmation.

Comment: Emails as notification is not available as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake can send emails now with `call system$send_email()`. You can call this within your tasks.

For example:

```sql
call system$send_email(
    'my_email_int',
    'felipe@example.com, dan@example.com, rajiv@example.com',
    'This is the subject',
    'This is the body'
);
```

Read more:

- https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-an-email-243741a0fe3

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not have this mechanism by default.
But to achieve this, you can use any of the following suggestions:

1. Write a JAVA [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html) (Python is in private preview) to
   send messages and attach as a subtask.
2. You can use [SNOWALERT](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SnowAlert-Data-Driven-Security-Analytics-using-Snowflake-Cloud-Data-Platform)
3. Or, as you wrote, use AWS mechanisms such as [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)